# Could not load type Error when creating a new Integration Services Package using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: ssis, bids

Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackageSigning100' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Comment: Verify if sql server and sql server management studio have the same version.

Answer (score 14):

Try unchecking the folowing setting in SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio:

Tools - Options - Business Intelligence Designers - Integration Services Designers - General - Check digital signature when loading a package

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Disabling "Check digital signature when loading a package" did not work for me. After some time I realized that I had forgotten to register my assembly in the GAC. I also had to work with embedded resources for third partly libraries.